# Write own exif tag in Android java

Tags: java, android, exif

I am currently working on a Android app written in Java in which I want to write data into the exif data of a photo. I want to create my own tags in the exif data.

```
Example: Email_Contact = email@example.com
```

I know about `ExifInterface` but as far as I now it only supports its own 140 tags and doesn't allow custom tags. Is there a way to write my own exif data with different tags. I have tried to create my own tags with `ExifInterface` but the following code doesn't seem to work.

```
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
String mString = "email@example.com";

try {
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(contentUri.getPath());
    exif.setAttribute("Email" , mString);
    exif.saveAttributes();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Summary: A way to write exif data with own tags in Android Java

Comment: How do you know this isn't working? Plus, why don't you pass `f` directly into the constructor?

Comment: It is not possible to write custom tags using `ExifIInterface`.  The problem is that exif tag names need to be mapped to (standard) numbers and value formats for storage.  There is no way to add the meta-metadata for a custom tag to the `ExifInterface` mapping tables.